# Random vectors and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables

[image]

Can someone give me some hints? The only thing I can think of is to prove that x1,...xn are linearly independent, but I have no idea about how to do it. Also, how to use the RANDOM VECTOR THEOREM? What does it exactly mean? How it works?

Comment: A bit unrelated to the question - can you maybe specify the book info? I am looking up this theorem online but cannot find anything.

Comment: I've been searching for that thrm but cannot find it as well

Comment: Hint: what is the probability that $x_1 \ne 0$?  What is the probability that $x_2 \notin \operatorname{span}(x_1)$?  What is the probability that $x_3 \notin \operatorname{span}(x_1, x_2)$?  etc.

Comment: Of course, you'll probably have to assume that $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are *independent* random vectors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heuristically speaking, relative to the standard bases on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, simply observe that in order for the random vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to also be an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m<n$, then the last $n-m$ coordinates of $x$ would have to be $0$. But 
$$
\Pr(x_i=0)=0,\;\forall 1\le i\le n
$$ 
and the result follows.

Now if you have a collection of $n$ vectors $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ that are linearly dependent, then there is at least one vector $x_i$ such that
$$
x_i=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_{i-1}x_{i-1}+a_{i+1}x_{i+1}+\cdots+a_nx_n.
$$
Similar to our argument in the original theorem, 
$$
\Pr(\text{a random vector} = x_i)=0.
$$

Comment: How does this proof work, for example, if $n=2$ and $\mathcal{V} = \operatorname{span} \langle (1, 1) \rangle$?

Comment: @Laars Helenius , that you write is not very convincing.

Comment: Point taken. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler, obviously your example requires $x_1=x_2$ and it is clear $\Pr(x_1=x_2)=0$.

Comment: @Laars Helenius , firstly, you prove the first part only when $\mathcal{V}=\mathbb{R}^m$. For the second part, $Prob(a\; random\; vector =x_i)$ has nothing to do here because $a_1,\cdots,a_{i-1},a_{i+1},\cdots,a_n$ depend on $x_i$. That you must write is that $x_i\in  span(x_j,j\not= i)=F$, a vector space of dimension $<n$; then if you fixed the $x_j,j\not= i$, then $prob(x_i\in F)=0$ (according to the first part that you did not prove).

Answer (score 0):

For i). $\mathcal{V}$ is defined by $n-m$ linear equations. Consider one amongst them, that we may write $x_1=\sum_{i>1} a_ix_i$. Let $v=(v_i)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that we fixed $v_2,\cdots,v_n$ and $v_1$ is free. The probabiliy that $v_1=\sum_{i>1}a_iv_i$ is $0$.

For ii). Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ where $v_k=(v_{k,i})$. We consider the matrix $A=[v_1,\cdots,v_n]$ written in the canonical basis. We suppose that this system has rank $k<n$. We may assume that the submatrix $(1..k,1..k)$ (denoted by $B$) is invertible and the submatrix $(1..k+1,1..k+1)$ (denoted by $C$) is not. Assume that we fixed $v_1,\cdots,v_k,v_{k+1,1},\cdots,v_{k+1,k}$ and $v_{k+1,k+1}$ is free. Then $\det(C)=v_{k+1,k+1}\det(B)+\sum_{i\leq k}a_iv_{k+1,i}$. The probability that $v_{k+1,k+1}=\dfrac{-\sum_{i\leq k}a_iv_{k+1,i}}{\det(B)}$ is $0$.